# Headless plugin using cdt api

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, headless

I am trying to create a headless plugin that would update the .cproject file of a C project in Eclipse.
For this, I use cdt API like :

```
CoreModel model=CoreModel.getDefault();
ICProjectDescription description = model.getProjectDescription(project);
```

This kind of code works fine with ui Eclipse but with my headless application,
I get the error : *java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workbench has not been created yet*

The full stack trace of the error is :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at rcpPluginProject.headless.Application.start(Application.java:234)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:660)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1468)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1441)
```

An error has occurred. See the log file
C:\Users\attiaschloe\Documents\Tasking_plugin\runtime-rcpPluginProject.application.metadata.log.

There is a cdt headless builder (source code in the link bellow) that uses these kind of api in headless mode but I get the same error when I run similar code.
https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/build/org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core/src/org/eclipse/cdt/managedbuilder/internal/core/HeadlessBuilder.java

Does someone know if there is something I need to do in order to make these api work in headless mode ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Do you have a stack trace showing exactly what is producing the error?

Comment: !MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.equinox.preferences".
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workbench has not been created yet.
 at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.getWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:95)
 ... at a lot od stuff

Comment: Yes, I just posted it above

Comment: The **full** stack trace, not just the last bit. Something  you are calling is referencing things that requires the GUI to be running, the full stack trace would show what is doing that. [edit] your question and add the full trace.

Comment: That stack trace is for a null pointer exception in your code, not an IllegalStateException. There is an error in line 234 of your Application code.